# scalaFX style sheet failing quietly

Tags: javafx-8, scalafx

I am just learning scalaFX/javaFX after years with swing and months with scalaSwing.   ScalaSwing had a few little issues that I felt weren't worth dealing with given the opportunity to update to something current. It Doesn't surprise me that I am having issues, but I am concerned.

Is this a problem with something I'm doing?  I need black backgrounds and this seems to be failing and not telling me why.

I can sort of get this to work if I add the button first then a rectangle.  I have tried wrapping the rectangle, but that is not the solution.

Thanks!

```
object Broken extends JFXApp {

  stage = new PrimaryStage {
    x = 0
    y = 0
    scene = new Scene {
      stylesheets add getClass.getResource("Dark.css").toExternalForm
      root = new FlowPane {
        padding = Insets(10)
        children = List(new Rectangle() {
          x = 0
          y = 0
          width = 100
          height = 150
          arcHeight = 20
          arcWidth = 20
          fill = Color.Red
        })
      }
    }
  }
}


object Works extends JFXApp {

  stage = new PrimaryStage {
    x = 0
    y = 0
    scene = new Scene {
      stylesheets add getClass.getResource("Dark.css").toExternalForm
      root = new FlowPane {
        padding = Insets(10)
        children = List(new Button("Works"))
      }
    }
  }
}
```

With this as Dark.css (file) in the same package

```
 //Dark.css
.root{
    -fx-font-size: 14pt;
    -fx-font-family: "Courier New";
    -fx-base: rgb(25,25,65);
    -fx-background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: I get the feeling that there is something intrinsic I'm missing, because if I just add and empty pane (StackPane) I get white, and I would think that I should always get black.  But if I add the Button I get Black.  So there is some content requirement?

Comment: How about you need some element that is Skinnable?  Button and Label both are and their inclusion makes the styles work.  In the end I need plenty of things that will extend Skinnable, so maybe this test is too focused.

Comment: Where is the`Dark.css` file located?

Comment: I put the Dark.css on the end of the post.

Comment: I mean it is physical location

Comment: There are various post here about that.  There are two choices about how to apply the css also.  
  Application.setUserAgentStylesheet(getClass.getResource("Dark.css").toExternalForm) with the Dark.css file in the same package as the test class will work.